# Az login without manual interaction

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to automate azure login in a powershell script and for that, I am using the below command as suggested in the Microsoft doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli#:%7E:text=az%20login%20%2D%2Duse%2Ddevice%2Dcode):

```
az login --tenant <tenant> --use-device-code
```

But the script is pausing here with the below warning expecting us to open browser and enter a code.

```
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code <code> to authenticate.
```

How do I automate the login in my powershell script?

Edit: The intention of this post is to understand the working of --use-device-code and get it working as expected.

Comment: There are two other options described in the linked guide (one using username and password) - have you considered them?

Comment: But I am looking for a way without passing username and password. The intention of this post is to understand the usage of --use-device-code. Let me edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Can you please provide more explanations as to why you wish to parse the "--use-device-code". Microsoft's implementation of the  OAuth v2 for the device-code is described in details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code. Otherwise, I would suggest you look away from parsing Credentials as bad-practice. Consider registering an App and Secret-Key as better alternative

Comment: Why not just use `az login --tenant <tenant>`. Both your command and this command expects a user to sign in once the browser is launched.

Answer (score 3):

***This is how `az login --use-device-code` works:***

[image]

***Enter the code in the given url:***

[image]

***Now in powershell you will get this type of output:***

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to run your script on an Azure VM with a managed identity. In that instance, no credentials are needed. All you need to do is run:

```
az login --identity
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-sign-in

Comment: something similar to this is exactly what I am looking for. I tried this but it's failing with the below error: ERROR: Failed to connect to MSI. Please make sure MSI is configured correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the MI configured?  Assuming this is an existing VM, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm#enable-system-assigned-managed-identity-on-an-existing-vm

Answer (score 0):

I'm supporting @ken W - ZeroNetworks anwer. We can use managed identity by passing az login --identity. But before that make sure you have used the AZ CLI by using the below command:

curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
- az aks install-cli
- az login --identity
Using outdated Az cli version will result in external authentication by using token which is a tidious task.